# How to use parent class default values in child class builder

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, lombok, builder

I am having two classes:
1]BaseCustomer.java

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Builder(builderMethodName="BaseBuilder")
public class BaseCusmtomer {
       private String cutomerId;
       private String age;
        @Default
       private Boolean isActive= true;
        @Default
       private String type = "XYZ";  
    }
```

2] Customer.java

```
@Builder
public class Customer extends BaseCustomer{
      private Customer(String cutomerId, String age, Boolean isActive, String type){
        super(customerId,age,isActive,type);
           }  
        }
```

3]Test Object

```
     Customer.builder().cutomerId("1").age("23").build();
```

ut while creating object using Customer builder it always take values of isActive and type as null, it should take default values from superclass. Is there anyway to do this?

Tried to call Child builder with default parent class values
but getting null values instead of default value.

Note: can't use Superbuilder as it is experimental feature.

Comment: Just use `@SuperBuilder`. Everything else is a big hassle. "Experimental" just means here: if you find a bug, its fix may have a lower priority than fixes for non-experimental features. But as `@SuperBuilder` has been around for a few years, you probably won't find any. ;)

Comment: agree but for the project, I am working they don't allow Experimental features.

Answer (score 0):

Since using @SuperBuilder is not an option for you, there is not much to do. One option is to create BaseCustomer "copy" constructor and create Customer by passing BaseCustomer to copy . Like this:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Builder(builderMethodName = "BaseBuilder")
public class BaseCustomer {
    
    
    protected String customerId;
    protected String age;
    @Default
    protected Boolean isActive = true;
    @Default
    protected String type = "XYZ";
    
    public BaseCustomer(BaseCustomer base) {
        this.customerId = base.customerId;
        this.age = base.getAge();
        this.isActive = base.isActive;
        this.type = base.type;
    }
}

@Data
public class Customer extends BaseCustomer {
    String name;
    
    @Builder
    private Customer(BaseCustomer base, String name) {
        super(base);
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

So as can be seen above, I marked Customer constructor with BaseCustomer parameter as @Builder. I added new parameter to Customer to see how it will work with additional fields. Now we can create Customer by building BaseCustomer first and then pass it with additional fields. For example:

```
Customer c2 = Customer.builder().base(BaseCustomer.BaseBuilder().customerId("1").age("23").build()).name("Name").build();
System.out.println(c2.getAge());
System.out.println(c2.getCustomerId());
System.out.println(c2.getType());
System.out.println(c2.getIsActive());
System.out.println(c2.getName());
```

This will print:

```
23
1
XYZ
true
Name
```

This has some advantages - you only pass single parameter (for base class) to Customer constructor and Customer constructor does not have to be changed for BaseCustomer field changes.